# Power supply noise/ringing caused by Jetson Nano booting and data processing

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, noise, 5v, ringing, smoothing-capacitor

I have a board where I use the Jetson Nano module as the CPU.

During the power-on sequence and data processing the Jetson introduces about 400mv peak to peak noise/ringing on the 5V (SMPS) rail causing my Hall effect sensors to misbehave.

I have tried additional decoupling capacitance, a ferrite bead + additional capacitor near the Jetson on the 5V line and a uni and bidir TVS on the 5V rail, so far nothing worked.

What is an effective way to combat this besides giving the Jetson its own power supply?

[image: The 5V supply]

Comment: Schematic please.

Comment: Personally, I would play with the compensation network as it determines the speed of the system's response to sudden load changes. By the way, what is **FS2**?

Comment: @RohatKılıç what exactly would you play around with then? And that's a polyfuse that has no business being there.

Comment: I mean R11-C13-C12. For example, decreasing the RC constant (e.g. decreasing R11) may lead the feedback network to respond faster. You can start with R11=10k, for example. I asked about FS2 because I first thought that it may cause a voltage drop across itself.

Comment: @RohatKılıç good call, will try that now. Thanks!

Comment: @RohatKılıç it worked, I ended up increasing it to 47k instead of decreasing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweaking the compensation network of the power supply solved the issue, I ended up increasing R11 to 47k (calculated 46k8).
Carefully (re)read the datasheet if your SMPS is not working properly, there's a lot you might have overlooked at first. Or try WeBench. I did both to be sure.